# Заменить данные в JSON файле

Tags: java, android, json

Есть JSON файл, который лежит на карте памяти:

```
[{
"name": "Mark1",
"id":"1",
"latlng": [49.797719,24.075343],
"content": {
    "test": "test_cont",
    "test1": "test1_cont",
    "test2": "test2_cont",
    "test3": "test3_cont"
}
}, 
{"name": "Mark2",
 "id":"2",
 "latlng": [49.797705,24.076287],
"content": {
    "test01": "test01_cont",
    "test11": "test11_cont",
    "test21": "test21_cont",
    "test31": "test31_cont"
}
}]
```

Потом считал его в String jsonData.

Дальше в нем надо заменить полностью содержимое content, исходя из того, какой ID был передан (если id==1 то первый контент, id==1 то второй и т.д.) строка StrToReplace, корой надо заменять уже сгенерирована.
Как мне лучше это сделать? А то с джейсоном еще плохо дружу.

Comment: наиболее правильный вариант - распарсить json, в распарсенном объекте сделать нужные замены (а это будет сильно проще - это уже будут объекты) и сериализировать назад в json.

Comment: Ну, у вас там объекты в массиве. Просто проходитесь по массиву и читайте `id`. Если тот, то делайте что-то.

Comment: Уже сделал. Прогнался по JSON массиву, нашел id, удалил content и вставил новый content из StrtoReplace.
Спасибо за помощь, а то сам тупил уже час где-то.

Comment: @YuraHalych, опишите ваше решение (с кодом) в ответе. Вам плюсы в репутацию, новые возможности на сайте, будущим посетителям вопроса - готовое решение и вообще всем польза.

Answer (score 1):

В итог сделал так:

```
JSONArray jsARR = new JSONArray(inputFile); //мой массив с данными JSON из файла, который ранее считал
    for (int i = 0; i < jsARR.length(); i++) { //Прохожу циклом по массиву
        JSONObject jsonObj = jsARR.getJSONObject(i); //Вытягиваю по одному объекту
        if (jsonObj.getInt("id") == MarkerID){ //тут проверяю сбегается ли имеющееся ИД с ИД в объекте
            //если да то
            JSONObject jsObj2 = new JSONObject(); //создаю новый JSON объект
            jsonObj.remove("content"); //Из основного удаляю нужные данные
            for (int k = 0; k<edits.size(); k++) { //Заполняю новый объект нужными елементами
                jsObj2.put(edits_name.get(k).getText().toString(),edits.get(k).getText().toString());
            }
            jsonObj.put("content", jsObj2); //Добавляю jsObj2 в jsonObj
        }
        outputFile += jsARR.getJSONObject(i).toString()+",";//Формирую выходной файл, который потом перезаписываю
    }
```

Может быть не все идеально сделано, но работает.